# $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} = 1$ implies $x_n \geq (1-\epsilon)y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $x_n$ and $y_n$ are a sequence of real numbers such that
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} = 1 \quad \mathrm{and} \quad \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} = -1.$$

Intuitively this says that as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the quotient $x_n/y_n$ remains within the the interval $(-1, 1)$. Of course this is only a limiting statement, so that for any fixed $n$ the quotient may take values outside $(-1, 1)$, but we expect this to happen less often as $n$ gets larger.

However I am following a proof (found here: [Asymptotics of Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4876203/asymptotics-of-brownian-motion))  that says the above implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have
$$x_n \geq (1-\epsilon)y_n \quad \mathrm{and} \quad  x_n \leq -(1-\epsilon)y_n.$$

But $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are only limiting statements so how can the above be true for a particular value $n$ or even all $n$?

Comment: $\limsup z_n = 1$ implies that for $\epsilon >0$ we have $z_n \geq 1- \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n\in \mathbb N$. I think it would be helpful to see how the proof continues and if this causes problems

Comment: In the link you gave, it does not say that the relations are true for all $n$ or even for all sufficiently large values of $n$. It only says that the relations hold for infinitely many $n$, which is precisely what limsup and liminf mean.

Comment: @Alex By the infinitely many do you mean there exists an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have $z_n \geq 1 - \epsilon$?

Comment: @BigbearZzz How would this apply to infinitely many $n$ but not necessarily sufficiently large $N$? Wouldn't we need to find some $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ $x_n \geq (1-\epsilon) y_n$ is valid?

Comment: No It could be true for all even integers.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure I understand. If it was only true for even integers wouldn't that violate the definition of $\limsup$? For example, see the first bullet point under "Interpretation" on the $\limsup$ Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior#Interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cited proof doesn't state that $x_n\geq (1-\varepsilon) y_n$.

Instead, it follows this reasoning:

As $\text{lim sup}\space \dfrac{x_n}{y_n}=1$, there exists a sequence $t_n$ such that $\dfrac{x_{t_n}}{y_{t_n}}\to 1$.

Then, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, if $n\geq n_0$, $\dfrac{x_{t_n}}{y_{t_n}}\geq (1-\varepsilon)\iff  x_{t_n}\geq (1-\varepsilon) y_{t_n}.$

As the author of the original text is only interested in the asymptotic behaviour of the Brownian Motion (that is, when $n\to\infty$), it is not relevant this only occurs after $n_0$.